# Multiple ajax calls made on form submission

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML form with jQuery catching the form submission but for some reason the browser is sending the Ajax call to the back-end twice. There are no javascript errors and everything works as expected including the back-end returning the expected json.

I have found other posts with the same issue but no responses have helped me. I have included my code below. Does anyone have any suggestions of why this may be occuring?

HTML:

```
<form action="/rating/create/<?php echo $jobId ?>" method="post" id="rating-form">
    <input type="hidden" id="Rating_jobId" name="Rating[jobId]" value="<?php echo $jobId ?>" />
    <input id="Rating_quality" type="slider" name="Rating[quality]" value="0" />
    <input id="Rating_service" type="slider" name="Rating[service]" value="0" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

javascript/jQuery:

```
    $('#rating-form').live('submit', function() {

        var action = $(this).attr('action');

        var dataset = {'Rating':{
                        'jobId':$('#Rating_jobId').val(),
                        'quality':$('#Rating_quality').val(),
                        'service':$('#Rating_service').val(),
                        },'ajax':'true'}

        d = new Date;
        dateCache = d.getTime();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: action +"?"+ dateCache,
            data: dataset,
            datatype: "application/json",
            cache: false
        }).done(function( response ) {

            if(response.success == 'true'){

                $('a.rating-'+ response.jobId).parent().remove();
                $.fancybox.close()

            } else {
                alert( response.error );
            }
         });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: FYI: You can skip the whole thing with `dateCache` as `POST` requests aren't cached at all. Also jQuery will do the same for you with `cache: false`

Comment: are you using firebug? do you see that two requests are being made? if not then maybe the problem is in the backend

Answer (score 1):

You can Avoid this by disabling button, when clicked and when you are done with ajax call, enable it.

Comment: Do mean disabling the button from being clickable? The button is only being clicked once but executing twice. I'm not sure your suggestion would help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than making the `rating-form').live('submit', function() {}`, why don't you just do

```
$("form").submit(function () {
  $(this).ajaxSubmit();
  return false;
})
```

and include [jquery.form.js](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/). For success callbacks, check the link!